# Write to cell in excel using c#

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I created a visual studio excel workbook project which contains ThisWorkbook class and I then included a functions class so that I can create my own excel function. I am trying to write a value to a cell using c# through the use of the function. I can write to the excel cell through the function class but only by creating a new application/workbook. So everytime I use this excel function, it will open new instance  of excel. Is there a way I can write to a cell in the current excel workbook that is already opened?

Comment: Like I know I can do this simply in the ThisWorkbook class doing something like.. 'Excel.Worksheet worksheet = ((Excel.Worksheet)Application.Activesheet); Excel.Range firstcol = worksheet.get_Range("A1","A1"); firstcol.Value2 = "hello";'

Comment: Please post the code you are using so we can help improve it... or at least something that represents your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably create a new Excel application, instead of connecting to the active Excel application.

Use the [GetActiveObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getactiveobject.aspx) to get your reference to the Excel application object.

Comment: Yes I did create a new excel application. So GetActiveObject allows me to connect to the existing excel application currently open?

Answer (score 2):

Look, I tried and this code works:

```
private void ThisWorkbook_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Excel.Worksheet ws = (Excel.Worksheet)(sender as Workbook).ActiveSheet;

    System.Random rnd = new System.Random();

    for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++)
        ws.Cells[i, 2] = rnd.Next(100);
}
```

so as you see you can access the Worksheet and use ws.Cells to manipulate cell values.

there are plenty of examples here:

[Understanding the Excel Object Model from a .NET Developer's Perspective](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa168292%28v=office.11%29.aspx)

Comment: Would I be able to do something similar to this outside the ThisWorkbook class? I want to do the exact same thing in my function class but I'm unable to call since its a private void. Thanks