# C# add content to Excel Worksheet

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

How can I add a value to an Excel Cell of the active Workbook using C#? I'm new to `VSTO C#` and can't find a solution that works for me...

This is my code  (from this question [Write to cell in excel using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7905217/write-to-cell-in-excel-using-c-sharp)) :

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace ExcelSDRAddIn
{
    public partial class UserControlSDR : UserControl
    {
        public UserControlSDR()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnTemplate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Excel.Worksheet ws = (Excel.Worksheet)(sender as Workbook).ActiveSheet;
            ws.Cells[1, 1] = "Value";
        }
    }
}
```

After running it I get the following exception on this line `Excel.Worksheet ws = (Excel.Worksheet)(sender as Workbook).ActiveSheet;`:

> An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in ExcelSDRAddIn.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Also tried with this:

```
    dynamic excelType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Excel.Application");
    excelType.Visible = true;
    excelType.Workbooks.Add();
    dynamic workSheet = excelType.ActiveSheet;

    workSheet.Cells[1, 1] = "Names";
    workSheet.Cells[1, 2] = "Age";
```

And returns:

> An exception of type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' occurred in System.Core.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: 'System.Reflection.TypeInfo' does not contain a definition for 'Visible'

Another example that fails:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application oXL;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook oWB;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet oSheet;
...
var Excel = new Excel.Application();
oXL = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
oWB = oXL.ActiveWorkbook;
oSheet = oWB.ActiveSheet;
oSheet.Cells[1, 1] = "Value";
```

Comment: What's the runtime type of sender coming in as? From what you have posted, it seems that the sender is either not of type workbook, so its null when you try to cast it as Workbook, or sender is coming in as null.

Comment: Additionally you might want to check an article i wrote to interact with Office without using Interop: https://jinishbhardwaj.wordpress.com/2016/06/21/com-interop-without-referencing-com-assemblies-using-dynamic-c/

Comment: I checked the article and added the code, but still doesn't work...see the updated Question

Comment: I would advice you to NOT use Interop, but rather use one of the good NuGet packages for Excel, like ClosedXml: https://www.nuget.org/packages/ClosedXML/

Comment: Please do not delete this question afterwards. I saw the previous question and now I see it's not there and link is broken.

Comment: @OriNachum I'll come back and make it a protected QA.

Comment: @AndersJH I followed your advice and installed ClosedXML, but I can't get it to insert a simple value to the worksheet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To access the workbook in your scenario you use:

```
  Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Workbooks...
```

MSDN Ref: [Programming VSTO Add-Ins](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb157876.aspx)

The following code example shows how to use the Application field to create a new workbook in an VSTO Add-in for Microsoft Office Excel. This example is intended to be run from the ThisAddIn class.

```
  Excel.Workbook newWorkbook = this.Application.Workbooks.Add(System.Type.Missing);
```

To do the same thing from outside the ThisAddIn class, use the Globals object to access the ThisAddIn class. For more information about the Globals object, see Global Access to Objects in Office Projects.

```
  Excel.Workbook newWorkbook = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Workbooks.Add(System.Type.Missing);
```

Edit: You need to use this code to get the active worksheet

```
  Excel.Worksheet ws = (Excel.Worksheet)Globals.ThisAddin.Application.ActiveSheet;
```

Comment: How can I achieve that without creating a new Workbook? I need to use the active Workbook

Comment: See my edit **Excel.Worksheet ws = (Excel.Worksheet)Globals.ThisAddin.Application.ActiveSheet;**

Comment: ws.Get_Range..  you can Google this stuff

Comment: Yes, now I get the rest. Thank you!

Comment: thx, one last thing, Vsto is SLOW! To get good speed see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356371/excel-interop-efficiency-and-performance and look up VSTOContrib

Answer (score 0):

From your method name `btnTemplate_Click` I bet you are using button to call this function. So the sender in this case is Button and not the `Workbook`. When you try to unbox sender as `Workbook` you will get null and you getting `NullReferenceException` while trying to access `ActiveSheet` property.

Please read the question in your linked reference one more time. It states that:

`I created a visual studio excel workbook project which contains ThisWorkbook class`

I am not sure how that class looks like but I think this is the place where method `private void ThisWorkbook_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)` should be hooked to some kind `Startup event.

Comment: You're right. I'm trying to add some content to the active sheet when I press a button from the User Control...it would help me a lot if you post a solution with an working example

Comment: Sorry, no. This is not the place to ask to build you full solution. Here you can ask for help to overcome your problem, but no one will post all solution.